# Custom Taxonomy isn't working from frontend post submitting

Tags: custom-taxonomy, page-template, front-end, wp-insert-post, register-taxonomy

**hi, i am working on a video sharing site project!**

I have Created a Template file where people can submit their post as video!
Everything was working very good, but the custom Taxonomy po*nstars isn't getting data. The tag is working, but when people submit po*nstars feild the posts pornstars feild got empty but everything is correct!
My template file is -

```
    <?php /* Template Name: Submit a Video */

$siteKey = get_theme_mod( "wp_script_theme_pro_recaptcha_site_key", "" );
$secret = get_theme_mod( "wp_script_theme_pro_recaptcha_secret_key", "" );

if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && isset($_POST['post_nonce_field']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['post_nonce_field'], 'post_nonce')):

    if ( get_theme_mod( 'wp_script_theme_pro_enable_recaptcha', 'no' ) == 'yes' && $siteKey != '' && $secret != '' ):

        if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])):

            $captcha = urlencode($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
            //$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            //get verify response data
            $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . $secret . '&response=' . $captcha);
            $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

            if($responseData->success):

                $pornstars = trim( $_POST['post_pornstars'] );

                $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

                $uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
$file = $_FILES['featured' ];
$uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . basename( $file['name'] );
move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'] , $uploadfile );
$filename = basename( $uploadfile );
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'menu_order' => $_i + 1000
    );
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );

                $post_information = array(
                    'post_title' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['video_title'])),
                    'post_content' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['video_description'])),
                    'post-type' => 'post',
                    'post_status' => 'pending',
                    'tags_input'    => $tags,
                    'tax_input' => array( $pornstars ),
                    'post_category' => array($_POST['category_selected'])
                );

                $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_information);
wp_set_object_terms($post_id,$pornstars,'post_pornstars');


                if($post_id){
                    // Update Custom Meta

update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $thumbnail_id );

                    update_post_meta($post_id, 'url_video', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['url_player'])));

                    update_post_meta($post_id, 'url_player', esc_attr($_POST['url_player']));

                    update_post_meta($post_id, 'wpscript_embed', esc_attr($_POST['video_embed']));

                    update_post_meta($post_id, 'wpscript_thumb', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['video_thumb'])));

                    if( ( isset($_POST['duration_hh']) ) && ( isset($_POST['duration_mm']) ) && ( isset($_POST['duration_ss']) ) ){
                        $duree_seconds = $_POST['duration_hh'] * 3600 + $_POST['duration_mm'] * 60 + $_POST['duration_ss'];
                        update_post_meta($post_id, 'wpscript_duration', $duree_seconds);
                    }

                    set_post_format($post_id, 'video' );
                }

                $succMsg = __( 'Thanks for submitting a video! Your submission is being moderated.', 'wp-script-theme-pro' );
            else:
                $errMsg = __( 'Captcha verification failed, please try again.', 'wp-script-theme-pro' );
            endif;
        else:
            $errMsg = __( 'Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.', 'wp-script-theme-pro' );
        endif;

            else:

        $pornstars = trim( $_POST['post_pornstars'] );

                $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

                $uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
$file = $_FILES['featured' ];
$uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . basename( $file['name'] );
move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'] , $uploadfile );
$filename = basename( $uploadfile );
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'menu_order' => $_i + 1000
    );
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );

                $post_information = array(
                    'post_title' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['video_title'])),
                    'post_content' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['video_description'])),
                    'post-type' => 'post',
                    'post_status' => 'pending',
                    'tags_input'    => $tags,
                    'tax_input' => array( $pornstars ),
                    'post_category' => array($_POST['category_selected'])
                );

                $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_information);
wp_set_object_terms($post_id,$pornstars,'post_pornstars');

                if($post_id){
                    // Update Custom Meta

update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $thumbnail_id );
                    update_post_meta($post_id, 'url_video', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['url_player'])));

                    update_post_meta($post_id, 'url_player', esc_attr($_POST['url_player']));

                    update_post_meta($post_id, 'wpscript_embed', esc_attr($_POST['video_embed']));

                    update_post_meta($post_id, 'wpscript_thumb', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['video_thumb'])));

                    if( ( isset($_POST['duration_hh']) ) && ( isset($_POST['duration_mm']) ) && ( isset($_POST['duration_ss']) ) ){
                        $duree_seconds = $_POST['duration_hh'] * 3600 + $_POST['duration_mm'] * 60 + $_POST['duration_ss'];
                        update_post_meta($post_id, 'wpscript_duration', $duree_seconds);
                    }

                    set_post_format($post_id, 'video' );

                    $succMsg = __( 'Thanks for submitting a video! Your submission is being moderated.', 'wp-script-theme-pro' );

                }

            endif;
        else:
            $errMsg = '';
            $succMsg = '';
        endif;

get_header(); ?>

    <!-- #primary BEGIN -->
    <div class="row margin-top-4">

        <?php if(get_theme_mod( 'wp_script_theme_pro_enable_user_video_submissions', 'yes') == 'yes') : ?>

        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">

            <?php if(!empty($errMsg)): ?><div class="callout error"><?php echo $errMsg; ?></div><?php endif; ?>
            <?php if(!empty($succMsg)): ?><div class="callout success"><?php echo $succMsg; ?></div><?php endif; ?>            

            <h1 class="widgettitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

            <?php if (is_user_logged_in()) : ?>

                <form action="" id="SubmitVideo" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <div id="html_element"></div>

                   <fieldset class="fieldset">
                        <legend><strong><?php _e( 'Video URL or iframe', 'wp-script-theme-pro' ); ?></strong></legend>

                                <div class="callout secondary text-center"><strong><?php _e( 'Currently we have not any options to upload videos directly!', 'wp-script-theme-pro' ); ?></strong></div>                    
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="medium-6 columns">                                
                                <label for="url_player"><?php _e('Video URL (flv or mp4)', 'wp-script-theme-pro') ?> <?php if(get_theme_mod('wp_script_theme_pro_enable_video_url_required_field', false) == true ) : ?><span class="required">*</span><?php endif; ?></label>
                                <input type="text" name="url_player" id="url_player" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['url_player'])) echo $_POST['url_player'];?>" <?php if(get_theme_mod('wp_script_theme_pro_enable_url_player_required_field', false) == true ) : ?>class="required"<?php endif; ?> />

                                <div class="callout secondary text-center"><strong><?php _e( 'OR', 'wp-script-theme-pro' ); ?></strong></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="medium-6 columns">                            
                                <label for="video_embed"><?php _e('Iframe / Embed Code', 'wp-script-theme-pro') ?> <?php if(get_theme_mod('wp_script_theme_pro_enable_video_embed_required_field', false) == true ) : ?><span class="required">*</span><?php endif; ?></label>
                                <textarea name="video_embed" id="video_embed" rows="4" cols="30" <?php if(get_theme_mod('wp_script_theme_pro_enable_video_embed_required_field', false) == true ) : ?>class="required"<?php endif; ?>><?php if(isset($_POST['video_embed'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['video_embed']); } else { echo $_POST['video_embed']; } } ?></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset class="fieldset">

                        <legend><strong><?php _e('Set Thumbnail', 'wp-script-theme-pro') ?></strong></legend>                    
                        <div class="row">                        
                            <div class="medium-6 columns">                                
                                                                <label for="featured"><?php _e('Upload thumbnail', 'wp-script-theme-pro') ?> <?php if(get_theme_mod('wp_script_theme_pro_enable_video_thumbnail_required_field', false) == true ) : ?><span class="required">*</span><?php endif; ?></label>
                                <input type="file" name="featured" id="featured" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['video_thumb'])) echo $_POST['video_thumb'];?>" <?php if(get_theme_mod('wp_script_theme_pro_enable_video_thumbnail_required_field', false) == true ) : ?>class="required"<?php endif; ?> />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset class="fieldset">
                        <legend><strong><?php _e( 'Video details', 'wp-script-theme-pro' ); ?></strong></legend>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="medium-6 columns">
                                <label for="video_title"><?php _e('Title', 'wp-script-theme-pro') ?> <?php if(get_theme_mod('wp_script_theme_pro_enable_video_title_required_field', true) == true ) : ?><span class="required">*</span><?php endif; ?></label>
                                <input type="text" name="video_title" id="video_title" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['video_title'])) echo $_POST['video_title'];?>" <?php if(get_theme_mod('wp_script_theme_pro_enable_video_title_required_field', true) == true ) : ?>class="required"<?php endif; ?> />

                                <label for="post_tags"><?php _e('Tags', 'wp-script-theme-pro') ?> <?php if(get_theme_mod('wp_script_theme_pro_enable_video_thumbnail_required_field', false) == true ) : ?><span class="required">*</span><?php endif; ?>(<small>Separate tags with commas</small>)</label>
                                <input type="text" name="post_tags" id="post_tags" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['post_tags'])) echo $_POST['post_tags'];?>" <?php if(get_theme_mod('wp_script_theme_pro_enable_video_thumbnail_required_field', false) == true ) : ?>class="required"<?php endif; ?> />

                                <label for="post_pornstars"><?php _e('Pornstars', 'wp-script-theme-pro') ?> <?php if(get_theme_mod('wp_script_theme_pro_enable_video_thumbnail_required_field', false) == true ) : ?><span class="required">*</span><?php endif; ?>(<small>Separate pornstars with commas</small>)</label>
                                <input type="text" name="post_pornstars" id="post_pornstars" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['post_pornstars'])) echo $_POST['post_pornstars'];?>" <?php if(get_theme_mod('wp_script_theme_pro_enable_video_thumbnail_required_field', false) == true ) : ?>class="required"<?php endif; ?> />

                                <label for="category"><?php _e('Category', 'wp-script-theme-pro') ?></label>
                                <select name="category_selected" data-width="auto">
                                    <?php
                                        $categories = get_terms( 'category', array( 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
                                        foreach ( (array)$categories as $category ): ?>

                                        <option value="<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $category->name;?></option>

                                    <?php endforeach;?>
                                </select>


                            </div>
                            <div class="medium-6 columns">
                                <label for="video_description"><?php _e('Description', 'wp-script-theme-pro') ?> <?php if(get_theme_mod('wp_script_theme_pro_enable_video_description_required_field', false) == true ) : ?><span class="required">*</span><?php endif; ?></label>
                                <textarea name="video_description" id="video_description" rows="8" cols="30" <?php if(get_theme_mod('wp_script_theme_pro_enable_video_description_required_field', false) == true ) : ?>class="required"<?php endif; ?>><?php if(isset($_POST['video_description'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['video_description']); } else { echo $_POST['video_description']; } } ?></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset class="fieldset text-center">

                        <legend><strong><?php _e('Submit a video', 'wp-script-theme-pro') ?></strong></legend>

                        <?php wp_nonce_field('post_nonce', 'post_nonce_field'); ?>

                        <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'wp_script_theme_pro_enable_recaptcha', 'no' ) == 'yes' && $siteKey != '' && $secret != '' ) : ?>
                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $siteKey; ?>" <?php if (get_theme_mod( 'wp_script_theme_pro_color_scheme', 'dark') == 'dark' ) : ?>data-theme="dark"<?php endif; ?>></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php /*<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
*/ ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                        <button class="button large expanded margin-top-2" type="submit"><?php _e('Submit a video', 'wp-script-theme-pro') ?></button>

                    </fieldset>

                </form>

            <?php else : ?>

                <div class="callout info"><?php printf(__('You must be logged to submit a video. Please <a href="%s">login</a> or <a href="%s">register</a> a new account.', 'wp-script-theme-pro'), '#wpst-login', '#wpst-register'); ?></div>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>

        <?php else : ?>

            <div class="small-12 medium-8 columns">
                <div class="callout info text-center">
                    <?php _e('Video submission is disabled.', 'wp-script-theme-pro'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'wp_script_theme_pro_enable_sidebar', 'yes') == 'yes' ) : ?>
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- #primary END -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And the Taxonomy register is -

```
    <?php //hook into the init action and call create_topics_nonhierarchical_taxonomy when it fires

add_action( 'init', 'wp_script_theme_pro_create_pornstars_taxonomy', 0 );

function wp_script_theme_pro_create_pornstars_taxonomy() {

// Labels part for the GUI

  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Pornstars', 'wp-script-theme-pro' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Pornstar', 'wp-script-theme-pro' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Pornstars' ),
    'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Pornstars' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Pornstars' ),
    'parent_item' => null,
    'parent_item_colon' => null,
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Pornstar' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Pornstar' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Pornstar' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Pornstar Name' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Pornstars with commas' ),
    'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove Pornstars' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used Pornstars' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Pornstars' ),
  ); 

// Now register the non-hierarchical taxonomy like tag

  register_taxonomy('pornstars','post', array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'pornstar' )
  ));
}
```

The Pornstars Taxonomy is always be empty, did m i missing something?
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: No one can help me?